# How do I keep the brush radius consistent while moving the camera when I'm texture painting on blender 4.0

Tags: texture-painting

Under the Brush settings I don't see Scene as the Radius Unit to be selected in order to keep the brush radius as the same size. On blender 4.0.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure that there's the option in Texture Painting

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature only in Sculpt mode - it was not determined to be supported for Texture Paint mode except for an addon that seems to have been withdrawn by the author, BPainter addon. Even then, I believe it was found to be rather buggy. The only option else is to use 3d view and 2d view to paint, and the scale 2d window will feel like a consistent scene width compared to the projection zoom in the 3d view.